# Find possible paths in a graph using neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner with graph data modeling, any help, tips or guidance will be appreciated. Forgive my lack of knowledge.

10 thousand feat idea is to be able to *translate* texts from one *language* to another in a certain *quality level*.

I have the following domain models:

- An activity (aka. `activity`)
- A source language (aka. `language_from`)
- A destination language (aka. `language_to`)
- A quality level (aka. `level`)

I have modeled the following graph to allow a user to ask for a translation from X to Y with a quality level Z.

[image]

Now let's say a user wants to translate from `en-us` to `de-de`. There are no links between the two nodes because business does not allow this path for domain reasons.

However it is possible to achieve such translation going through `en-us`->`fr-fr` then `fr-fr`->`de-de`.

My questions are:

1. Is the above graph model appropriate for such query?
2. What would the query look like using neo4j cyphers?

Any tips to get me on the right track would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can model your data in a more straight-forward way.

You could use `Language` nodes directly connected by `TRANSLATE` relationships with the `level` as a property on the relationship. It's simpler, directly maps to your domain problem and you don't need other nodes for your query.

```
(Language {name: 'de-de'})-[:TRANSLATE {level: 7}]->(Language {name: 'fr-fr'})
```

A variable length query finds translations through mulitple languages:

```
MATCH path=(lang:Languag {name: 'de-de'})-[:TRANSLATE*1..3]-(other_lang:Language {name: 'en-us'})
RETURN nodes(path)
```

Here you could also filter for a certain level:

```
MATCH path=(lang:Languag {name: 'de-de'})-[:TRANSLATE*1..3]-(other_lang:Language {name: 'en-us'})
WHERE all(x IN relationships(path) WHERE x.level > 5)
RETURN nodes(path)
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the idea. I think you are right, the `translation` should really just be a relationship instead of a node. Also, your idea allows to get rid of the distinction between source and destination language.